# MongoDB - Performing an upsert on an array if arrayFilters are not satisfied

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document stored in mongo:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d1a08d2329a3c1374f176df"),
"associateID" : "1234567",
"associatePreferences" : [ 
    {
        "type" : "NOTIFICATION",
        "serviceCode" : "service-code",
        "eventCode" : "test-template",
        "preferences" : [ 
            "TEXT", 
            "EMAIL"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "URGENT_NOTIFICATION",
        "serviceCode" : "service-code",
        "eventCode" : "test-template",
        "preferences" : [ 
            "TEXT"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I am basically trying to query one of the elements of the associatePreferences array based off of its type, serviceCode, and eventCode and add a new value to the preferences array. However, if that combination of type, serviceCode, and eventCode is not present, I would like to add a new element to the associatePreferences array with those values. This is my current query:

```
db.user_communication_preferences.update(
   {'associateID':'testassociate'}, 
   {$addToSet:{'associatePreferences.$[element].preferences':"NEW_VALUE"}}, 
   {arrayFilters:[{'element.serviceCode':'service-code-not-present', 'element.eventCode':'event-code-not-present','element.type':'URGENT_NOTIFICATION'}]}
)
```

This query works if all of the arrayFilters are present in the an element of associatePreferences, but it does not add a new element if it is not present. What am I missing?

Comment: Bumping into the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation pipeline to check the existence of the element, then append the element to `associatePreferences` array conditionally. Finally, using the aggregation result to update back your document.

```
db.user_communication_preferences.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "associateID": "testassociate"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "filteredArray": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$associatePreferences",
          "as": "pref",
          "cond": {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$pref.type",
                  "URGENT_NOTIFICATION"
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$pref.eventCode",
                  "event-code-not-exists"
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$pref.serviceCode",
                  "service-code-not-exists"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "needAddElement": {
        $eq: [
          {
            "$size": "$filteredArray"
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "associatePreferences": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$associatePreferences",
          {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $eq: [
                  "$needAddElement",
                  true
                ]
              },
              "then": [
                {
                  "type": "URGENT_NOTIFICATION",
                  "serviceCode": "service-code-not-exists",
                  "eventCode": "event-code-not-exists",
                  "preferences": [
                    "TEXT"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "else": []
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]).forEach(result){
    db.user_communication_preferences.update({
        _id : result._id
    }, {
        $set: {
            "associatePreferences" : result.associatePreferences
        }
    })
}
```